# How to disable blinking cursor in Gnome 3.8?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, settings, cursor

There is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49606/how-do-i-disable-the-blinking-cursor-in-gnome-terminal) proposed solution to disable the blinking cursor in Gnome terminal. However, it no longer seems to work for Gnome 3.8. The option `/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default` in Gconf does not exist.

So, what is a working solution for Gnome 3.8?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try (in a terminal):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-blink false
```

As your can see the key has been moved to `org.gnome.desktop.interface` (via GSettings), so you can access it via `dconf-editor` if you prefer so.

Comment: To disable only in gnome-terminal in Gnome 3.8 and above, try: `dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:<profile-uid>/cursor-blink-mode "'off'"`. The profile UID can be obtained from the profile preferences. Thanks to [ArchWiki docs for the help](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME#Disable_blinking_cursor).

Answer (score 4):

None of the above worked for me on Debian Jessie.  I worked out the following solution from [recent gnome docs](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Terminal/FAQ?action=show&redirect=Terminal%2FFAQ#How_can_I_stop_the_cursor_from_blinking.3F)

```
## Find profile, see also Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Profile ID
gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList list

## Substitute the relevant profile for UUID below - but include all / and :
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:UUID/ cursor-blink-mode off

## Disable globally (except gnome-terminal has its own config)
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-blink false
```

---

To automate this for all profiles, enter in bash

```
for uuid in $(gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList list | tr -d "[',]"); do
    gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:${uuid}/ cursor-blink-mode off
done
```

This retrieves the UUIDs from the profile list as above with `gsettings`, and removes unneeded characters `[',]`. The resulting list is used in setting the `cursor-blink-mode` to off.

Comment: Well, that is certainly intuitive, and obviously much better than the old "toggle the checkbox" interface... WTF are they thinking?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  To disables cursor blinking desktop-wide:Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/interface/cursor_blink --type bool false
```

To disable blinking just for Gnome Terminal’s Default profile:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/cursor_blink_mode --type string off
```

<sup>Source:M.Friedrich</sup>

Comment: Hi Mitch. This does not work. The cursor in the Terminal is still blinking. Furthermore, it is exactly the same approach I have referred to and also had described that it is not working with Gnome 3.8.

Comment: I have changed the commands in my answer.  Try it, and let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately still not working. Does it work for you?