# Where's the gnome terminal config file located?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to find the gnome terminal config file in Ubuntu 16.04, but having no luck whatsoever. I want the cursor not to stop blinking, and there's probably a timeout parameter I can change, but I can't find the file to do it. I know it can be done through dconf-editor, but for some reason that's not working (I think I removed some dependency or other).

Comment: dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/

Comment: The comment of @utopiceexpress worked for me on 17.04. Loading the dumped config can be done with `cat dump.txt | dconf load /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/`

Comment: @utopiceexpress Some of the settings are outside of the "profiles:" directory, so you should rather do `dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/`. See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/967517/backup-gnome-terminal/967535.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no config file.

The `gnome-terminal` manages all its settings through `dconf` (or `gconf` in old Ubuntu releases) which is comparable to the Windows registry. It's a binary file optimized for quickly reading its values, you can not edit or view it manually like a text document.

If your `dconf-editor` or whatever tool you're trying to use is not working, you have to correct *that* error first.

Just for completeness, but probably you already saw those links (which mention only `dconf`/`gconf`, of course):
[How do I disable the blinking cursor in gnome-terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/49606/367990)
[How to disable blinking cursor in Gnome 3.8?](https://askubuntu.com/q/311699/367990)

Comment: *"you can not edit or view it manually like a text document."* But there is dconf dump and load http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/199836/49853 http://askubuntu.com/q/522833/40581

Comment: Turns out my dconf-editor wasn't borked after all. I just had a bad case of the dumb.

Comment: @LiveWireBT You're right, there are always alternative tools. They can translate the binary dconf registry file into plain text and back as well as modify it. From the question's wording, I was just somehow thinking that there could be more stuff messed up and not only the graphical dconf-editor...

Answer (score 17):

The comments to the original post by *eexpress* and *Fabian Strietel* deserve special recognition. Between those two, I have been able to easily copy my preferences (several profiles and other minor stuff) from VM to VM. Many thanks!

**Save**:

```bash
dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/ > ~/gterminal.preferences
```

**Install**:

```
cat ~/gterminal.preferences | dconf load /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/
```

Answer (score 6):

Following on ajaym62's answer I could achieve backup and restoration of the properties with the following commands:

```
dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/ > ~/dev/help/gnome-terminal.properties
cat ~/dev/help/gnome-terminal.properties | dconf load /org/gnome/terminal/
```

I had first to install the `dconf` tool:

```
sudo apt install dconf-cli
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want the cursor not to stop blinking

`GNOME Terminal` doesn't offer a separate option for this, but it respects `GNOME`'s default which is located in the `dconf` key `/org/gnome/desktop/interface/cursor-blink-timeout` (in seconds).

Beef up this to a giant value if you'd prefer the cursor to keep blinking, e.g.

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/cursor-blink-timeout 86400
```

Answer (score 2):

**NB: you won't have to install any program or remove any file.**

To edit your `gnome-terminal` preferences **without actually opening or using** `gnome-terminal` go to

```
/root/usr/share/applications
```

Then locate **Terminal** in the folder.
Then open its properties by right clicking on **Terminal**.
There you'll see **command**.
This is actually what happens when you open terminal. So to edit the preferences, change the command to `gnome-terminal --preferences`.
Voila

After "repairing" the settings. Just close the preferences and then remove `--preferences` from the command in the properties window.
Now just open the terminal as you normally would.

**EDIT** : If you are in a command line interface, then just use the command `gnome-terminal --profile=default`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  You implied that one navigates with a GUI file interface.  I got to step 3 before realizing your answer does not apply to a command line interface.

Comment: @wallyk yes it doesn't. Because I had somehow messed up with my  gnome-terminal settings and I knew where was the fault. So I wanted a way to keep my configuration as it is and "repair" the terminal. As many methods mentioned about using dconf tools and deleting the configuration file, something that I wanted to keep as it is and change it back.