# How do I script changing the color scheme in gnome-terminal?

Tags: 22.04, gnome-terminal, colors, dconf

How do I script changing from the light mode to the dark mode?
In it GUI I do this:
**preferences>profiles>Unnamed>Colors>Bultin-in schemes (here I choose either black-on-white or white-on-black**.

[As far as I know](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774394/wheres-the-gnome-terminal-config-file-located), there is no config file. I use Ubuntu 22.04LTS Desktop and have no `/org` in my filesystem. How might I automate the process of changing the color scheme scripting the whole process with `dconf` or similar tools? The goal is to run the script via cron that changes from **black-on-white** to **white-on-black** at 2pm and vice versa at 7am.

I already know how to launch `gnome-terminal` with desired settings saved in a profile, e.g. `gnome-terminal --profile=dark`. This is not what I want to achieve because I want the already opened windows to change the color scheme.

Comment: Did you look under `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/` in `dconf`?

Comment: @FedKad I've added more information to my question in response to your comment.

Comment: I am not talking about any `/org` directory. I am talking about the dconf key path. Please, try `dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, use the command

```
dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/
```

and find the relevant "profile id" that has `visible-name='Unnamed'`.

Using the command `dconf write key_path new_value`, you can change the values of the following keys:

```
/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/<profile_id>/background-color
/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/<profile_id>/foreground-color
```

e.g. changing to dark theme:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/background-color "'#000000'"
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/foreground-color "'#ffffff'"
```

where `:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9` is your profile id.

Comment: `dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/` gave me this `[:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9] background-color='rgb(255,255,255)' font='Monospace 21' foreground-color='rgb(0,0,0)' use-system-font=false use-theme-colors=false`
This **Unnamed** profile is not a profile that I created, it is on every Ubuntu Desktop installation.
`b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9` seems to be its id.
I figured out how to do this manually from `dconf-editor` 
but I need a solution that is non-interactive and can be run
as a script via cron.

Comment: Use the `dconf write key_path new_value` command in a script. Please, note that these values are _per user_, so your cron script should be run from the current user.

Answer (score 1):

I needed an interactive solution to deal with trendy tools that set the foreground color without checking the background color.

This function is part of my Bash profile. It allows me to switch between color schemes using the command `colors light` and `colors dark`.

```bash
function colors() {
    local black="'#000000'"
    local white="'#ffffff'"
    local background_color
    local foreground_color
    local default_profile="/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9"

    case $@ in
        "dark")
            background_color="$black"
            foreground_color="$white"
            ;;
        "light")
            background_color="$white"
            foreground_color="$black"
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Choose 'dark' or 'light'" >&2
            return 1
            ;;
    esac

    dconf write "$default_profile/background-color" "$background_color"
    dconf write "$default_profile/foreground-color" "$foreground_color"
}
```

[vale](https://github.com/errata-ai/vale/issues/424) and [rain](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/rain/issues/67) use dark grey or navy blue text in their help output which is impossible to read on a dark background.

With `colors light`, I can read the output of these tools:

[image: Dark foreground color is visible on a white background.]

With `colors dark`, the output of these tools is unreadable:

[image: Dark foreground color is invisible on a black background.]