# Why does the cursor freeze in terminals?

Tags: command-line

I've noticed that whenever I open a terminal the cursor blinks *about* 10 times and then freezes.

Is there a particular reason for this? What can the idea be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug, but a feature to save energy. Refer to this bug report on launchpad:

- [The cursor in active terminal window stops blinking after ten seconds.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/838381)

You can even stop the cursor blinking, refer to this question to see how:

- [How do I disable the blinking cursor in gnome-terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49606/how-do-i-disable-the-blinking-cursor-in-gnome-terminal)

Comment: your answer hits the spot!! thanks :D ...saving energy is least to expect

Answer (score 0):

The previously provided answer to this question does not work in Xubuntu 18.04, where the cursor blinking timeout for GTK applications is apparently controlled by xfconf rather than dconf.

If you're a Xubuntu user, you can do the following to make the cursor keep blinking in GTK-based applications (which includes gnome-terminal, xfce4-terminal, gedit, pidgin and many others):

1. Open `Settings Editor` from the `Settings` menu.
2. Select the `xsettings` "channel" on the left side of the interface.
3. Click `New`.
4. The name of the property needs to be `/Gtk/CursorBlinkTimeout`
5. Set it to be an integer property.
6. Specify a large number (but less than 2 billion).
7. Click `Save`

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the question was simply "why".