# Xubuntu 18.04: basic terminal emulator where the cursor blinks normally?

Tags: gnome, dconf, xfce4-terminal

This is related to [why does the cursor freeze in terminals?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397234/why-does-the-cursor-freeze-in-terminals).

Many terminal emulators (including the native xfce4-terminal) are built with GTK. Unfortunately, GNOME decided that cursor blinking was bad for the environment and by default cursors in GTK applications stop blinking after a short period of time.

The solution to this that has been provided in the past was to install the dconf editor and adjust the value of: /org/gnome/desktop/interface/cursor-blink-timeout

Unfortunately it seems this setting is not honored in Xubuntu 18.04, as the cursor continues to stop blinking after about 10 seconds. (xfce4-terminal, gnome-terminal, lxterminal...)

I installed `terminology` but that has a whole bunch of dependencies and really doesn't look at all like a conventional terminal emulator. But it does have a cursor that blinks, and keeps blinking.

Is there some trick to getting dconf changes to be recognized? Failing that, can anyone recommend a lightweight terminal with a blinking cursor? (Even xterm would be OK.)

Comment: `konsole` has continuous blinking provided the window is in focus. Whether it's lightweight or not is your call.

Answer (score 0):

I've learned that invoking `xterm -bc` will cause xterm to always blink the cursor regardless of whatever default behavior might otherwise be imposed. Blink speed can be customized with `-bcf` and `-bcn`, per the man page.

I've also discovered that GTK-based terminal emulators (and any GTK-based application) running in Xubuntu's xfce *can* have their cursor blinking behavior controlled, but apparently it's through xfconf and not the usual dconf. If you want to have the cursor blink for longer than 10 seconds in a GTK application, you can refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1085030/883153).