# Terminal flashing between current and previous screen

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. After upgrading the terminal will sometimes, but not always, flash between the current screen and the previous screen. Here are some examples:

1. The output of an 'ls' command will flash on and off the screen.
2. But when I press enter to start a new line, sometimes--but not always--the output of ls will stop flashing and instead the newline will begin flashing.
3. Sometimes vim will start flashing between the current place and a previous place, such as right after a search.
4. This also happens when I opened just sh within a bash terminal. (I was hoping the issue was just with my .bashrc, though I haven't changed it in months and didn't have any issues in 12.04.)

This is incredibly annoying, and has made the terminal essentially unusable.Unfortunately, google-ing for a half hour hasn't shown anyone running into similar problems, either on 14.04, other versions of ubuntu,or other versions of linux.

UPDATE: I'm not sure if this helps identify the problem, but the text stopped blinking when I turned the cursor blinking off using these instructions [How do I disable the blinking cursor in gnome-terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49606/how-do-i-disable-the-blinking-cursor-in-gnome-terminal). However the problem isn't totally fixed because now the text will disappear for a moment when I type.

Comment: I have this exact problem too.. I have tried all kinds of things.
At some point I thought that it had something to do with the NVidia card I am using, but the problems are only in the terminal. So I doubt it. I am using Gnome terminal 3.6.2 using zsh 5.0.2 and usually tmux. The flashing occurs outside of tmux as well, however. This is a really annoying problem, as I use the terminal a lot, for Javascript in development in VIM mostly, and git. It seems to me that the problem is related to Gnome terminal. I have switched to Sakura and have so far been flash free.

Comment: I have this problem too, but using Sakura didn't fix it. I also have an NVidia card, terminal 3.6.2, zsh 5.0.5, and no tmux.

Comment: This problem seems to occur (for me at least) in both gnome-terminal and guake, so it might not be terminal-specific.

Comment: (I also tried Sakura as posted above, but it didn't help.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible this is a compiz/nvidia bug.

I noticed very similar "screen flashing" that seemed tied to screen redraws, e.g. chunks of the screen would redraw strangely as the cursor blinked, or if I turned off the blinking cursor, would just fail to redraw at the right time.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1314367/ describes the following workaround:

> To fix it, you get CompizConfig Settings Manager (ccsm) and you go
>   down to "Workarounds" in the "Utility" Category and check the box that
>   says "Force full screen redraws (buffer swap) on repaint".

...which seems to have worked for me. At least for now.

Answer (score 1):

Many years later I've started getting this same issue after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04. It's happening with Regolith desktop and gnome terminal located at `/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator`.

Fixed by installing the old `st` terminal with `apt install stterm` and then changing my `~/.config/regolith/i3/config` file to launch `/usr/bin/st` when pressing `$mod+Return` instead of x-terminal-emulator.